# C pass by reference "returns" incorrect content

Tags: c, parsing, reference, parameter-passing

I want to read some values from a file using a function and pass them to main. 
The file has specific format:

> string double char

For example 2 lines:

> blahblah 0.12 G
>      testtesttest 0.33 E

I have the following program. Although values are printed correctly in the function, in main only a few of them are printed. The rest are 0.00000 and no character is printed as well. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int read_file(const char *filename, double **prob, char **sense);

int main(){

    double *iprob;
    char *sense;

    read_file("test.txt", &iprob, &sense);

    printf("Main: %lf %c\n", iprob[0], sense[0]);

    return 0;
}


int read_file(const char *filename, double **prob, char **sense){

    FILE *fp;
    char line[100], temp[80];
    int i = 0;

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"File %s not found!\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }

    //*prob = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * 100);
    //*sense = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);

    while( fgets(line, 100, fp) != NULL){

        prob[i] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
        sense[i] =  (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));

        if ( sscanf(line, "%s %lf %c", temp, prob[i], sense[i]) < 3 ){

            fprintf(stderr, "Parsing error detected at line %d!", i);
            fclose(fp);
            return 0;
        }
        else{

            printf("%lf %c\n", *prob[i], *sense[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Your `iprob` is not initialized. You might want to uncomment the line `//*prob = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * 100);`. Please compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: You don't open your file, `fp`. Have you posted the correct code?

Comment: @MOehm You are right.. I forgot to copy this piece of code. Fixed now.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch What do you mean it's not initialized? I tried to uncomment the line you suggested before even posting here. No luck. Added -Wall -Wextra -g and it just complains about unused variables, nothing more.

Comment: By the way, if the file fails to open you are assuming it is because it is not found - there are other reasons why it might not open, permissions for example.  Use: `perror(filename);`

Comment: BTW, C has no [pass-by-reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) call. Everything is passed by value. But when you call `read_file("test.txt", &iprob, &sense);` you are passing *by value* the *address* of `iprob`. This is not a reference. Please **read a good *C* programming book** (you are very confused, and we don't have time to teach you C)

Comment: `prob[i]` Can you tell how many elements are in that array and where they are allocated?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for the advice, although I didn't ask anyone to teach me C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a double pointer to `double` in your functions, because you want to update the pointer passed in from `main`.

The problem is, that the allocated array is in `*prob`, and therefore you have to address the elements of that array as `(*prob)[i]`.

`*prob[i]` is the same as `*(prob[i])`. `prob` is the pointer to a pointer; it has only one element, so to speak, so any index except 0 is invalid here.

Below is a correction of your code:

- It reads in as many entries as there are in the file by reallocating memory as needed.
- It returns -1 on failure and the number of items when successful, so you know how many items you can safely address.
- You should `free` both pointers after use.

So:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int read_file(const char *filename, double **prob, char **sense);

int main(){

    double *iprob = NULL;
    char *sense = NULL;
    int i, n;

    n = read_file("test.txt", &iprob, &sense);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Main: %lf %c\n", iprob[i], sense[i]);
    }

    free(iprob);
    free(sense);

    return 0;
}

int read_file(const char *filename, double **prob, char **sense){

    FILE *fp;
    char line[100];
    int size = 0;
    int i = 0;

    *prob = NULL;
    *sense = NULL;

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) return -1;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
        char temp[80];

        if (i >= size) {
            size += 8;

            *prob = realloc(*prob, size * sizeof(**prob));
            *sense = realloc(*sense, size * sizeof(**sense));

            if (*prob == NULL || *sense == NULL) {
                fclose(fp);
                return -1;
            }
        }

        if (sscanf(line, "%79s %lf %c", temp, &(*prob)[i], &(*sense)[i]) < 3) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Parsing error detected at line %d!", i);
            fclose(fp);
            return -1;
        } 

        printf("%lf %c\n", (*prob)[i], (*sense)[i]);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
*prob = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * 100);
*sense = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);

while( fgets(line, 100, fp) != NULL){

    //prob[i] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
    //sense[i] =  (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));

    if ( sscanf(line, "%s %lf %c", temp, &(*prob)[i], &(*sense)[i]) < 3 ){

        fprintf(stderr, "Parsing error detected at line %d!", i);
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
    else{

        printf("%lf %c\n", (*prob)[i], (*sense)[i]);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: @user3674296 is right BLUEPIXY the demo linked does not work.

Comment: @WeatherVane It seems to no problem If it is data within the range of expected.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I gave it the two lines quoted by OP. I was going to post something similar to yours, but when I added a print of line 2 in main it gave the wrong values.

Comment: @WeatherVane [DEMO for print of line 2 in main](http://ideone.com/F8aGsr) Correct value is displayed without problems.

Comment: I'm afraid your demo just hangs when I try it here - compiled with MS Visual C.

Comment: @WeatherVane I was tested with clang, gcc and MSVC2010, I got the same correct result. Do you have to say that "it does not work"  what grounds?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I am sorry - I didn't notice you had decided to read `stdin` instead of "test.txt" as OP did.

Comment: Changing of DEMO is for online compiler. But But it is no different. stdin be treated like a file.